# android phones supporting ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-touch

Which android phones support Ubuntu? I have seen a video that Ubuntu phone can be made PC by docking. Can someone suggest me which phone to buy that have such docking facility. If not docking, USB cable will be fine. If you know, then give me brand name and model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Android OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) is based on the Linux kernel, so theoretically all android phones should be able to run Ubuntu for Android. Then the question, which phone will run Ubuntu with the best performance. For that, you will have to look into the hardware specifications and read some performance reviews. Smooth performance with the regular OS will carry over to smooth performance with Ubuntu.

The docking feature you are referring to utilizes the microUSB port. This will connect to a USB port on your computer. All androids have this port. They use it for charging the battery, adding music, etc.